# Tetromino(kind of tetris) strategy, probabilty to complete an area

Tags: probability, game-theory

There is a kind of tetris game. I need to fill an area (4 column and 6 row) with the pieces below. The pieces has no rotation and reflection.

```
1   2   3  4    5   6  
##  #   #  ##   ##  # 
 #  ##  #   ##  ##     
        #
```

When the game starts, you will have a random piece which you may use that piece or you can throw it. After that, you will get another piece randomly (all six pieces have the same probability) and so on.
The point is to complete the whole area by using maximum 10 pieces. You use the piece or throw it both count.

The question is how to play this game perfectly. I mean, how can I decide a piece to throw or keep and where to place it. Every move will change the probability of completing the puzzle up to 10 move and, I need to keep that probability higher. What would the best strategy be? Thanks for help.

Comment: You only expect to get $30$ blocks to fill $24$ squares, so on average you can only afford to discard two pieces, often only one. You're likely to need that flexibility at the end, so I suspect it will never be advisable to discard pieces up to the last few moves. In fact I expect that there will be quite few cases where you should discard a piece if it's possible to use it.

Comment: Let's firm up the rules.  Suppose piece 4 is the first to be placed.  Does that make it impossible to proceed?  Rotation and reflection are disallowed (per your wording of the Question).  So an empty space appears on the bottom at left.  Will it be possible to fill that open space?  If so, how?

Comment: @hardmath: It's just "a kind of tetris game", it's not Tetris :-) There's nothing about the pieces falling down to the bottom row.

Comment: @joriki: So the new piece can be placed anywhere on the board?  Can a piece be moved or assigned a position after it is originally admitted (not "thrown")?  As the Question is presently worded: "I mean, how can I decide a piece to throw or keep and where to place it."

Comment: @hardmath: I should let the OP speak for himself, but my understanding was that each piece must be placed as it arrives, before the next one is seen, and then stays there.

Comment: You can place a piece anywhere on the area. Pieces are not falling down. When a piece comes up you can throw it, you dont have to use it, but it will be counted anyways. For ex., you get the third piece as first random piece. number of all combinations with 3.piece up to 10 move = x, number of all combinations with all other pieces up to 9 move = y. So, if y >x that means you should throw the 3. piece because you will have a higher chance to complete the puzzle up to 10 move. (using 3. Piece makes it harder to complete the puzzle up to 10 move) @hardmath

Comment: So, when do you decide on the position of pieces?  Immediately when a piece is kept, or at the end, when all pieces are known?

Comment: when a piece is kept. @hardmath

Comment: My intuition also says don't discard anything up until last move or two, if you really think you can afford it. Also as for the perfect placing, I'd say that you can't elaborate what is the best move by some "nice math formula" because the setup of the game is very specific. You could probably write a programme that does this for you though.

Comment: Can you show an algrithm for this program. @prosinac

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I didn't write the programme, I just wanted to point out that there is probably no "nice formula", but rather that you'd have to write programme that plays optimally.